# Change UITableView cell.detailTextLabel colour on highlight

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

The default colour for text in a UITableView when selected is white. I want to change this to dark grey. I managed to change the main title label text by doing this:

```
cell.selectedTextColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
```

How can I do this for the detailTextLabel though when it is highlighted/selected?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subclass UITableViewCell. Then override the setHighlighted:animated Method:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
       [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
       if (highlighted) {
           self.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
       } else {
           self.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
       }
}
```

You may end up wanting to override the setSelected:animated method too.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blue color];
```

Comment: This would just change the detailTextLabel color for the default state, not when it is highlighted.